# How to split string before number

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string `1 blahblahblah 2 sdsdsdsdsd 3 uuuuuu 4 eeee 5 abcdef`
I would like to output

```
1 blahblahblah
2 sdsdsdsdsd
3 uuuuuu
4 eeee
5 abcdef
```

I have tried to add `\n` before every number by using `re.split` but it didn't work

```
re.split(' (?=[1-9]:)', line)
```

Comment: Please describe what you attempted with `re.sub` and the result you got.

Comment: First, `re.split` is for splitting a string into a list, not replacing with newlines. Secondly, why do you have a colon in the regex after the number? And did you mean `(?:[1-9)`?

Comment: Is there any way to do this without RegEx?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works just fine:

```
re.sub(r'(\d+)', '\n\\1', input)
```

Demo:

```
>>> print(re.sub(r'(\d+)', r'\n\1', input))

1 blahblahblah 
2 sdsdsdsdsd 
3 uuuuuu 
4 eeee 
5 abcdef
```

The expression `(\d+)` matches 1 or more digits, and I replace that with a newline followed by the matched digits (via the capturing group).

Answer (score 1):

Use a [group](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

```
>>> s = '1 blahblahblah 2 sdsdsdsdsd 3 uuuuuu 4 eeee 5 abcdef'
>>> import re
>>> print(re.sub(r'([0-9]+)', r'\n\1', s))

1 blahblahblah 
2 sdsdsdsdsd 
3 uuuuuu 
4 eeee 
5 abcdef
```

To remove the first newline, you can add a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
>>> print(re.sub(r'(?<!^)([0-9]+)', r'\n\1', s))
1 blahblahblah 
2 sdsdsdsdsd 
3 uuuuuu 
4 eeee 
5 abcdef
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do the substitution without inserting a newline before the first number:

```
In [62]: print(re.sub(r'\s(\d)', r'\n\1', line))
1 blahblahblah
2 sdsdsdsdsd
3 uuuuuu
4 eeee
5 abcdef
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `re`:

```
>>> s = '1 blahblahblah 2 sdsdsdsdsd 3 uuuuuu 4 eeee 5 abcdef'
>>> for i,word in zip(*[iter(s.split())]*2):
    i = int(i)
    print('{i} {word}'.format(**locals()))
```

Output:

```
1 blahblahblah
2 sdsdsdsdsd
3 uuuuuu
4 eeee
5 abcdef
```